# How to start buidling and app using stackexchange API as it does not support localhost?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stackexchange-api

How can I use [Stackexchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) when it does not support localhost or any dev URL with port number?

It is very difficult to push code to Heroku as it was suggested in one answer on StackOverflow during development as it slows down development work.

I have registered my application with the API but I cannot specify port number there and therefore I cannot implement the functionality of importing user data into my Rails app.

Comment: use a dev url without port number. I use `ngrok.io`

Comment: Thanks a lot @SergioTulentsev. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install `ngrok` locally . Start the ngrok server & use its url. See ngrok(https://ngrok.com) for more details